# Can you get a husband that gives you free money like ysolda in skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I accidentally picked Female to be my gender.
Is the a husband that gives you 100 gold a day just like Ysolda. If so, could you explain where and how I can marry him?

Comment: What's a freeloader?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freeloading :P

Comment: The reason I chose female coz she looks sexy as anything

Comment: @Moose ummm... This is a video game xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is a husband that is a Merchant, and there are quite a few of them. For a complete list you can go [here](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Marriage#Male_NPCs) but here are the names as they currently are in the game:

- Balimund
- Filnjar
- Halbarn Iron-Fur
- Moth gro-Bagol
- Quintus Navale
- Revyn Sadri
- Sorex Vinius
- Wilhelm

I think only Halbarn requires the Dragonborn DLC, the rest are just out and about in the world. (can get more details on their locations on that wiki page link above).

Comment: Thank you I will check to see if each of them look good. :-) :-)

Comment: @TheElectricMoose Just for what its worth, as the top of that wiki page also states that you can marry anyone in the game regardless of gender and/or race of your character and the NPC.

Comment: I don't want to be lesbian or gay

Comment: @TheElectricMoose Any merchant person should give you their wages :)

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter if your character is male or female, you can still marry Ysolda.